# exponential likelihood with normal prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, exponential-distribution

If I have a likelihood function based on the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ , why would a normal prior with a very large variance be inappropriate for $\lambda$?

Comment: What is the basis for the question? What would lead you to even consider a normal prior?

Answer (score 2):

What have you considered? Did you try drawing the prior for example?

Consider the feasible values for $\lambda$ and the support of the prior:

- what values can $\lambda$ take?
- what values will the prior say that $\lambda$ can take?

Edit: If the prior for $\lambda$ is $N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma>>\theta$, what -- to a rough approximation -- is $P(\lambda<0)$?

Comment: So basically right now lambda>0. but the prior may give a negative value of lambda. is that correct?

Comment: You might like to consider the $N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ case where "large variance" implies $\sigma>>\theta$ (for positive $\theta$ say). In that case, what's a lower bound on the probability of a negative $\lambda$? What will happen as $\sigma$ grows larger relative to $\theta$?